# Let ≤ be an ordering on a set A. Prove that if ≤ is a well-ordering then it is a linear-ordering.

Tags: proof-writing

So i understand that to be an ordering, you have to satisfy the conditions of being reflexive, anti-symmetric, and transitive and for linear-ordering , there should be any a,b such that a ≤ b or b ≤ a but I can't seem to find the connection unless maybe defining some elements to exist in the ordered set.

Comment: What is your definition for a well-order if it is not a priori a linear order?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma An order relation for which for every non-empty subset there is a minimum. Not mention of linear ordering, although it gets implied since minimum must in particular be comparable to the other elements of the subset. So, it does require a proof.

Comment: Then my answer does work.

Comment: Aren't reflexive and anti-symmetric contradictory?

Comment: @Acccumulation antisymmetric is $x \le y, y \le x \to x=y$. not $x < x$ is called asymmetric, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

For any pair $a \neq b$,$\{a,b\}$ must have a minimum.